# Axios send array in post request

Tags: javascript, post, axios

I want to post a array with a axios post request.
This is the array I want to post

```
validMonths2019 = ['01', '02', '03', '04']
```

and this is how I tried to post it.

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', {
          contractId: contractId,
          contractCompletionQuote: contractCompletionQuote,
          iterations: iterations,
          validMonths2019: validMonths2019
        })
```

But I just get undefined instead of the array

Comment: You need to show more code, especially the context in which the axios request was made. What happens if you log `validMonths2019` to console right before making the axios request? Does it contain the array you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the thing. Either you wrapped the whole thing on a JSON.stringify({
 Prop: value,
Prop2:value
})

Or set the Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Comment: Actually not... You don't need to wrap or set content-type. The object he sent was undefined before.